# How to set up Safari to always show status bar

Tags: safari, preferences

I am using Safari 6.0.2 (8536.26.17) within Mac OS X 10.8.2.

I would like to know how to set Safari so that, whenever a new window is opened, the status bar is always turned on.

I think this used to be a preference setting but it doesn't appear to be available in this version.

Whenever I open a new window, there is no status bar.

I know how to use the keyboard shortcut to turn it on and off. I'm looking for a way not to have to use the shortcut each time.

Is this doable? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found a command-line solution, opening up the Terminal and typing in the following:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.Safari ShowStatusBar -boolean true
```

Answer (score 1):

Odd, because I have the Status Bar visible, and every time I open a new window, it is visible. I wonder if you don't have some kind of extension causing yours to not show. The View > Show Status Bar command is not for each window, but is global, so it should work all the time.